# Quebrar linhas no CSS sem usar elementos a mais

Tags: html, css

Tenho 2 elementos `inline` e preciso fazer com que a linha seja quebrada, sem eu precisar adicionar `display: block;` ou se possível adicionar mas não ocupar 100% da linha:

```
<div class="box-error-page cb">
    <h1 class="title-page-error title-error-default fleft">
        404
    </h1>

    <h2 class="title-not-found title-error-default">
        Ops! Página não encontrada
    </h2>

    <p>Não foi possível localizar o link que você estava buscando.</p>

    <a href="" class="cb">Ir à página inicial</a>
    <a href="javascript:history.go(-1);" class="cb">Voltar à página anterior</a>
</div>
```

No caso os 2 links no final, deveriam quebrar linha, queria ver se tem alguma forma, sem a necessidade de usar elementos a mais, apenas pra quebrar a linha, sei que daria pra fazer com `UL>LI`.

Comment: Não entendi porque a pergunta foi downvoted.

Comment: É "normal" aparecer downvote sem justificativa. Poucos assumem o que fazem (sem ofensa a quem o fez porque não sei quem foi) e/ou justificam o motivo.

Comment: Uma pena, porque achei a pergunta bem legítima. E vi que dar downvote tira um ponto da sua reputação, então não faz muito sentido sair distribuindo.

Comment: @Marta, esse tipo de downvote injusto acaba se auto-corrigindo. Seu 1º comentário é bastante construtivo nesse sentido. Ah, sim, ++ na sua resposta, legal a técnica :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Você pode usar o pseudo-elemento `:after`

```
a:after{content:""; display:block; clear:both}
```

O `:after` funciona a partir do IE8. Com ele você cria um elemento no CSS, então não precisa mexer no seu HTML.

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/xqbyeq6k/

Comment: Obrigado!! Era isso mesmo. :D