# Como quebrar linhas entre links sem que os mesmos ocupem toda a largura do elemento pai?

Tags: html, css

Estive olhando estes dois tópicos que tratam de quebra de linha entre tags:

- [Quebrar linhas no CSS sem usar elementos a mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29822/quebrar-linhas-no-css-sem-usar-elementos-a-mais)
- [Como quebrar linha entre tags CSS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/243304/como-quebrar-linha-entre-tags-css)

Ambos resolveriam meu problema se não fosse por um detalhe: eu preciso que os links `<a>` tenham a propriedade `display: inline-block` para que eu possa aplicar um `scale` no `:hover`. Sem essa propriedade o `scale` não surte efeito.

Por outro lado, se eu aplicar `display: block` aos links (ou não especificar nenhum `display`), eles irão ocupar toda a largura da *div-pai* onde estão, o que não é desejável. Gostaria que o link ficasse restrito apenas à área do texto que ele contém, e não à largura toda da *div-pai*.

Algo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu poderia simplesmente colocar um `<br>` após cada link, mas sei que o `<br>` semanticamente não pode ser usado para quebrar linhas entre tags, apenas em textos.

Existe alguma forma de quebrar essas linhas entre as tags `<a>` sem que as mesmas ocupem toda a largura da *div-pai*?

Comment: Definir um width?

Comment: Como seria se os textos variam de tamanho?

Comment: Tô achando que vou ter que enfiar uma tag entre os links... sempre achei isso ruim, ou será que é normal? :/

Comment: Podes definir um max-width... Mas Css é assim, adptar seguindo a necessidade... Ou ainda pode colocar os links em outra div, e usar o clear:both, tem n possibilidades...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui incluindo as tags `<a>` dentro de tags `<p>` (deste que `<a>` contenha apenas texto), conforme menciona esta **[especificação HTML5](http://w3c.github.io/html/single-page.html#phrasing-content)**.

Como as tags `<p>` ocupam toda a extensão da *div-pai*, irá forçar a quebra de linha. Bastou apenas ajustar a margem-padrão que o `<p>` possui para obter o espaçamento desejado:

```
<style>
p{
  margin: 5px 0;
}
</style>
```

Ficando assim:

```css
p{
  margin: 5px 0;
}

div{
  width: 200px;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 15px;
}

a{
  background: aqua;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .1s ease;
  transition: transform .1s ease;
}

a:hover{
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div>
   <p><a href="">Link um</a></p>
   <p><a href="">Link dois</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Da para fazer sem a tag `<p>` usando `display:flex` no pai e a orientação do *container-flex* em coluna e não em linha como é no *default*

Veja o exemplo:

```css
div{
  width: 200px;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* coloca os itens em coluna um abaixo do outro */
  align-items: flex-start; /* alinha os itens a esquerda para não ocuparem a linha inteira e apenas o próprio conteúdo */
}

a{
  background: aqua;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .1s ease;
  transition: transform .1s ease;
}

a:hover{
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div>
   <a href="">Link um</a>
   <a href="">Link dois</a>
</div>
```